# Ionic : Canot open

Tags: ionic-framework

I start develop first app with ionic, My problem is i cannot open single post.

My view is :-

```
    <div class="col col-33">
    <a href="#/books/en.html">   
      <div class="col-info"> 
         <h3>KAM</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

And the controller is :-

```
  .state('app.books', {
    url: "/books",
    abstract : true,
    views: {
      'books': {
        template: "<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.books.singlebook', {
        url: '/books/:id',
        templateUrl: 'js/app/views/singlebook.html',
        controller: 'singlebook'

  })
```

Why the APP not open `singlebook.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things have gone wrong which are causing your app not functioning. First the controller you mentioned is not a controller file. It is your app.js file. You should have a file with a name controllers.js and in it you use something like

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {


})
```

to use your controller.

Also your `template: "<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>"` is a mistake as well. It should be a directory path, not tags.

Your view also does not have a `<body ng-app="starter">`, and if it has a referring view it should also have `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` to refer to your view. Or if you have an index.html, which have the elements I just mentioned, it should have tags like these: `<ion-view view-title="Home"><ion-content>` and your div should reside within these tags.

It is impossible to give all the reasons why the post can't be opened.

Please refer to the tutorials to start with:

https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html